# 下記サイトにあるような見た目のER図を作成するツールが知りたい

Tags: database

以下サイトにある見た目のER図を生成するツールを探しています。
ご存知の方は教えていただけると幸いです。

http://geneontology.org/sites/default/files/public/diag-godb-er.jpg

ER図生成ソフトを探しているのではなく、
上記サイトと同じ見た目のER図を生成するツールが何かを調べています。

Comment: このER図はなんというツールで作られたものかわかりますか？という質問でしょう。人力画像検索ですね。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。Google画像検索を使い探した所、見つかりました。

以下のツールのようです。

SQLEditor: https://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/index.html

Comment: よくあるツールですが、見やすい出力ですね。